# docker run hello-world results in "Incorrect Usage" error: "flag provided but not defined: -console"

Tags: docker

When running `docker run hello-world` I get an "Incorrect Usage" error (full output pasted below).  I'm running the following:

- Docker 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
- docker-containerd 0.2.3 (commit 9048e5e)
- runc v1.0.0-rc4
- Linux kernel 4.1.15
- Using buildroot 2017.11 (commit 1f1a242) to generate custom toolchain/rootfs
- systemd 234

Seems as though I can pull the hello-world image down properly, as it is included in `docker images` output.  Wondering if there is an incompatibility between docker/containerd/runc?  Or maybe something obvious?  First time working with docker.

Additionally, I've run a docker check-config.sh script I found that states the only kernel configuration features I'm missing are optional.  They are CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS, CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB, CONFIG_AUFS_FS, /dev/zfs, zfs command, and zpool command.  Everything else, including all required, are enabled.

---

Output:

```
# docker run hello-world
[  429.332968] device vethc0d83d1 entered promiscuous mode
[  429.359681] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethc0d83d1: link is not ready
Incorrect Usage.

NAME:
   docker-runc create - create a container

USAGE:
   docker-runc create [command options] <container-id>

Where "<container-id>" is your name for the instance of the container that you
are starting. The name you provide for the container instance must be unique on
your host.

DESCRIPTION:
   The create command creates an instance of a container for a bundle. The bundle
is a directory with a specification file named "config.json" and a root
filesystem.

The specification file includes an args parameter. The args parameter is used
to specify command(s) that get run when the container is started. To change the
command(s) that get executed on start, edit the args parameter of the spec. See
"runc spec --help" for more explanation.

OPTIONS:
   --bundle value, -b value  path to the root of the bundle directory, defaults to the current directory
   --console-socket value    path to an AF_UNIX socket which will receive a file descriptor referencing the master end of the console's pseudoterminal
   --pid-file value          specify the file to write the process id to
   --no-pivot                do not use pivot root to jail process inside rootfs.  This should be used whenever the rootfs is on top of a ramdisk
   --no-new-keyring          do not create a new session keyring for the container.  This will cause the container to inherit the calling processes session key
   --preserve-fds value      Pass N additional file descriptors to the container (stdio + $LISTEN_FDS + N in total) (default: 0)

flag provided but not defined: -console
[  429.832198] docker0: port 1(vethc0d83d1) entered disabled state
[  429.849301] device vethc0d83d1 left promiscuous mode
[  429.859317] docker0: port 1(vethc0d83d1) entered disabled state
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: flag provided but not defined: -console.
```

Comment: It looks like mismatched versions of dockerd and runc. Are you building this yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`-console` option was replaced](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/commit/244c9fc426aeb1993e0ba871b5ee181b190338b6#diff-cc79fe39318bd23b3e2242c0aaac24fd) with [`--console-socket`](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/commit/7df64f88866962d3ee56dc67039f0ea1e13c49cd#diff-cc79fe39318bd23b3e2242c0aaac24fd) in runc [Dec 2016](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/commits/master/exec.go) for v1.0.0-rc4.

So I would guess you need an older version of runc or a newer version of Docker.

If you are building Docker yourself, use Docker 17.09.0-ce or an older release of runc. I'm not sure if that's v0.1.1 or just an earlier 1.0 like v1.0.0-rc2

If you were upgrading packages, something has gone wrong with the install. Probably purge everything and reinstall Docker.

Comment: I am building myself via buildroot, but the default versions of docker/runc built by my buildroot version seem to have the `-console` / `--console-socket` mismatch.  I'll confirm tomorrow morning by upgrading docker version and rebuilding.  That information is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Verified that downgrading runc fixed the compatibility issue.  Notified buildroot devs, they will revert runc to older version for upcoming 2017.11 release.  Looking to bring all docker related packages to latest versions for future 2018 release.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting incompatibility issue between Docker Engine and the runc package

**Issue description:** when trying to spin up / start a stopped container the following error is thrown:

```
 docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: flag provided but not defined: -console
```

**Root cause:** the error described above is most likely to happen after an update / upgrade of the system, especially when the latter has not been updated for a long time. Seems the update itself does raise the version of the runc library in that particular case which might lead to incompatibility of the updated runc package with the Docker engine that's using it.

**Solution / Fix (in steps):**

1. [**On Docker Host**]

   Detect the appropriate version of the runc package that is supposed to be
   compatible with the currently running version of Docker by checking both the version of
   Docker and the version of the runc package currently in use

```
docker --version

runc --version
```

2. Download the binary file of the runc package from the official repository in GitHub:
   https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/releases

   The downloadable files should be listed within the assets section of the selected release.
   There are several files listed in assets depending on the architecture of the machine
   Docker is running on; hence pick the right one: runc.xxx
3. (Take this step if the download is done on antoher machine, via a browser for example)

   Transfer the downloaded file to the machine where the runc library needs to be fixed / replaced.

   Make sure you have created the destination folder on the target host before starting the
   transfer, for example: /downloads/docker/runc_package/

```
scp runc.xxx user_name@host_ip_address:/downloads/docker/runc_package/
```

4. [**On Docker Host**]

   Move into the destination folder where the runc package is downloaded / transferred

```
cd /downloads/docker/runc_package/
```

4. [**On Docker Host**]

   Back up the currently installed runc package.

   Most likely it is installed in [/usr/sbin/runc] or [/usr/local/sbin/runc], but
   check it first

```
cp /usr/sbin/runc /downloads/docker/runc_package/runc_x.x.x
```

5. [**On Docker Host**]

   Rename (if necessary) the newly downloaded / transferred runc package to runc

```
mv runc.xxx ./runc
```

6. [**On Docker Host**]

   Copy the new runc package into the [/usr/sbin/runc] or [/usr/local/sbin/runc] folder,
   so that to replace the currently used version of runc

```
sudo cp runc /usr/sbin/runc
```

7. [**On Docker Host**]

   Check the currently used version of the runc package (it should match the new one)

```
runc --version
```

8. [**On Docker Host**]

   Try to spin up a new container using the Docker run command.

   If everything  is set up correctly, the command should successfully create and
   run a new container using the specified Docker image

```
sudo docker run <docker_image_name>
```